# C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, derived-class, computational-finance

I'm trying to code Put-Call Parity function in CallOption and PutOption derived class.
I'd like this function passes the reference of the object as argument.

This is the signature of the function in the `CallOption.hpp`

```
double PCParity(const PutOption& put_option) const;
```

and similarly in `PutOption.hpp`

```
double PCParity(const CallOption& call_option) const;
```

I, of course, included CallOption.hpp in PutOption.hpp and reciprocally.

But I get the following errors:

- identifier 'PutOption' is undefined.
- missing type specifier - int assumed. Note C++ doesn't support default-int.
- syntax error: missing ',' before &

Does it mean that I cannot call two derived classes simultaneously at the compiling time?

Any help is very much appreciated. :(

Comment: You probably have a circular include path.

Comment: ***I, of course, included CallOption.hpp in PutOption.hpp and reciprocally.*** That is your bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve header include circular dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies)

Comment: Your question should include a [mcve]  Trying to guess what you did wrong based on your explanation of what you think you did isn't a very good approach to problem solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @drescherjm for the comments, while you replied I kept searching a solution to my problem. As you said I should use the forward declaration like stated here:
[What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c).
Indeed I should include `CallOption.hpp` in `PutOption.cpp` and similarly for the CallOption class. Then, declare at the top of `CallOption.hpp`, as follows:

```
Class PutOption;
Class CallOption: public Option
{
}
```

Many thanks :)